# WSO2 - Micro Integrator dashboard - Not connected to RDBMS user store but to file store

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-micro-integrator

I have a running micro integrator 4.2.0 instance connected to RDBMS user store MySQL database. Calling an API deployed under the carbon applications of this micro integrator is working fine using the admin admin user. However, when i open the dashboard / users screen, it shows the following message: User management is not supported with the file-based user store. Please plug in a user store for the correct functionality

Is any configuration at the dashboard level needed? the documentation only suggests to add the data source and user store to the micro integrator configuration. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have missed disabling the file-based user store in the Micro Integrator which is used by default for authentication and authorization for the management API.

You need to add the following config to the `deployment.toml` of the Micro Integrator.

```ini
[internal_apis.file_user_store]
enable = false
```

Refer the following doc for more information and the configuration steps,

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/user_stores/setting_up_a_userstore/#disabling-the-file-based-user-store

Comment: this config is not present under deployment.toml file and i added this:
[user_store]
# type = "read_only_ldap"
class = "org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager"
type = "database"

Comment: @user666, you need to have the `[internal_apis.file_user_store]` config as well in the deployment.toml in addition to the `[user_store]`

Comment: i added this config myself and its working now. Thank you